# Premix dry herbs for easy oil pasta

Tags: pasta, herbs

How normal is it to use premixed dried herbs with pre-toasted garlic as a quick oil pasta preparation? Is it presumable that one can just use supermarket brands in making one's own premixes, or is it still incumbent to use just-dried herbs?

In Italy, I was able to buy some packs of mixed dry herbs. Printed on them was an obvious "aglio e olio". The packs varied in content, but all contained garlic. One variant had sun-dried tomatoes, another had a lot of chili flakes. I think I spotted some dried basil and parsley.

Comment: I think it is difficult to answer the question "how normal is it to..." because there is great variation in the way many people do things in the kitchen.  In this case, there certainly is nothing wrong with using pre-mixed, dry herbs, but I am not sure what you really want to know.  Further, I am not sure what you mean by "supermarket brands".  Is there a way to reword your question to make it more precise and answerable?

Comment: I also had some trouble phrasing "how normal is it..." Since oil pasta dishes normally start with steeping garlic in hot oil, adding herbs dry and fresh, then mixing with noodles. But it's exactly that contrast -- what cities/cultures do the quick-dry herb-oil steep-seasoned method for making quick oil pasta dishes? Supermarket just means stuff like McCormick.

Comment: I don't think you've clarified anything.  Most of the time, in Italian cuisine, the preference would be to use fresh herbs.  Dried herbs are usually used as a matter of convenience, as illustrated by what you found at the store.  McCormick is a company that sells dried herbs, spices and spice/herb blends.  They would certainly be just as useful as one's own dried herbs and spices. So, I am still not clear about what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Do it...taste it..if you like it go on doing it...there is no normal and abnormal in the kitchen as in life, it is subjective not objective. I do it sometimes. And I mix also the dry herbs worth dry bread for schnitzel or to sprinkle on oven cooked vegetables

Answer (score -1):

In my personal experience, in the USA you will get fresher/better herbs at a lower price in the bulk spice section of your co-op/natural foods store than you will as "supermarket brands." YMMV.